# DIV content does not overflow

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, overflow, doctype

**The code below works properly in all browsers but IE.
The overflow doesn't work.  Thanks.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
#scroll {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div id='scroll'>
    <div class='box' style="background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class='box' style="background-color: black;"></div>
    <div class='box' style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
    <div class='box' style="background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div class='box' style="background-color: green;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?  Much appreciated!   - Jimmy

Comment: Appears fine for me - what version of IE where you specifically looking at?

Comment: It works in IE 5.5 (weird), 8, 9. It does not work in 6. I can't open IE 7...

Comment: The code (above) as is does not work in IE 8 for me.  Remove position:relative it does.  Haven't tried it on other browsers.  Thanks for the tips guys!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the "**position:relative;**" from the .box CSS definition, I believe it'll work in FF and IE 6.0.

Edit: I've tested it - and it works in FF 3.6.8 and I.E. 6.0.28 (i.e. keeps the 100px boxes within the scroll div).